# JOptionPane.showOptionDialog shows no buttons?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

The following code shows a dialog as expected, apart from having no buttons:

```
  final JPasswordField passwdField = new JPasswordField();
  passwdField.setColumns(20);
  final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[] {  passwdField };
  int res = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Enter Password", "Login", 
                  JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                  null, inputs, "");
```

shows the following dialog (Java 6.2?, Windows 7 64-Bit):

[image]

Why are there no OK / Cancel button? (btw, the dialog is not resizable, so I don't know if they are just outside the visible frame)

(Also, pressing Enter does not close the dialog, "x" closes the dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the inputs array. Read the API and it will tell you that it should be different. I usually use an array of String, each String representing a button String, or sometimes I use a mixture of Objects, mixing components and Strings. For e.g.,

```
  JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField(10);
  Object[] inputs = {passField, "OK", "Cancel"};
  int res = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Enter Password", "Login", 
           JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
           null, inputs, "");
  if (res == 1) {
     System.out.println("Password is: " + new String(passField.getPassword()));
  }
```

Comment: Fair enough. Using the `passwdField` as second parameter instead works.

Comment: @Carsten: the order doesn't matter as long as you take it into account when deciding what to do with the result returned (here held by `res`).

Comment: I mean second parameter of `showOptionDialog`, not the `inputs` array

Comment: @Carsten: yes, the Object parameter can hold a JPasswordField or even a JPanel that holds a complex GUI if desired. JOptionPanes can be very flexible and powerful, more so than most realize.